# ng-repeat on jsobject with nested json

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs

I've been at this for days and I can only acknowledge my lack of knowledge in the matter. 
I have an array of articles which I receive from a $http request and iterate into the following structure by calling sortArticles(articles). The reason is to simplify the structure of the httpData object and get rid of some nested arrays (I have removed some code for readability).

article.service.js:

```
function sortArticles(httpData){
    var sortedList = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < httpData.length; i++){
        var date = new Date(httpData[i].Date);
        var tmpObj = {Name: httpData[i].Name, 
                      Price: httpData[i].Price, 
                      Date: date};
        // I want my controller to receive a list with all articles
        // linked to a specific date in the same array. Reason being;
        // Each date will become a tab in the view:
        if(typeof sortedList[date] == "undefined"){
           sortedList[date] = [];
           sortedList[date][0] = tmpObj;
        }else{
           sortedList[date][sortedList[date].length] = (tmpObj);
        }

    }
    return sortedList;
}
```

Now to my controller that received the sortedList above looks like this:

article.controller.js:

```
angular
.module('app')
.controller('ArticleController', ArticleController);

ArticleController.$inject = ['articleservice'];

function ArticleController(articleservice) { 

    var vm = this;
    articleservice.getArticles()
        .then(function(data){
            vm.sortedList = data;
            for(var i in vm.sortedList){
                console.log("i: ", i, " ### vm.sortedList[i]: ", vm.sortedList[i] + "\n");
            }
        },
        function(reason){
            console.log(reason);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

In the console.log() above everything is presented in the browser's console like this:

i:  Wed Sep 02 2015 ### vm.articles[i]:  [object Object],[object Object].... etc
i:  Wed Sep 03 2015 ### vm.articles[i]:  [object Object],[object Object].... etc

Which to me is a proof the array is working.

but how do I present this in angular with ng-repeat? 
I just get a blank page with all of the below attempts:

```
<span ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.sortedList">{{key}}</span>


<span ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.sortedList">{{value[key]}}</span>

<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.sortedList">
   <div ng-repeat="article in value[key]">{{article.Name}}</div></div>
```

the final goal in semi-psuedo code is something like this

```
   <md-tab ng-repeat="date in vm.sortedList" label: {{date}}>
        <tabContent>
             <p ng-repeat="article in date">
                   <table>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Name</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>article.name</tr>
```

... etc etc

Please help me internet, you're my only hope

Comment: where is the problem exactly? console.log the array to see if it is structure as it's supposed to, after you got that right, the "semi-pseudo" code part pretty much correct if you also add {{}} or ng-bind when printing variables.

Comment: Well, it just doesn't work. Page is blank. I've tried to recreate this in a fiddle and I think and hope I didn't make a silly mistake here: http://jsfiddle.net/hhyz3yqh/1/

Comment: Take a look at the answer bellow, you can not iterate through an array with strings as keys. replace the dates with integers and you will notice that it works. It would be wised to create an object such as {date: date, [obj1, obj2]} or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript array indexes must be integers.

The following:

```
vm.sortedList = [];
var date = "May 2015";
vm.sortedList[date] = [];
```

Will add a property called `May 2015` to `sortedList`, it will not push anything into the array. If you log it you can see that the length of `sortedList` is still `0`.

So the following:

```
<p ng-repeat="dates in vm.sortedList">
```

Will iterate over an empty array.

Use an object instead:

`vm.sortedList = {};`

And use the following to iterate over it:

`ng-repeat="(key,value) in vm.sortedList"`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lka8qx4m/